# does openXML(C#) support generating number fields that are formatted (like 1,000,000)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

i have existing code that generates a spreadsheet from excel using OpenXML.  It works fine but i always have to go into the spreadsheet afterwards and add formatting.

Is there anyway in my C# code I can specify that i want a column formatted with a certain number formatting) commas, decimals, etc?

any links to examples would be great.

here is how i am saving data now:

```
 public void SetCell<T>(string column, uint rowIndex, T value)
    {
        SheetData sheetData = _positionSheet;
        Cell cell = GetCell(sheetData, column, rowIndex);
        string stringValue = value == null ? "" : value.ToString();
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(stringValue);
        switch (typeof(T).Name)
        {
            case "Date":
            case "DateTime": 
                cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
                break;
            case "Int32":
                cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                break;
            default:
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                break;
        }
    }
```

below is the GetCell() method (even though i guess thats not really relevant for the question:

```
 static private Cell GetCell(SheetData sheet, string column, uint rowIndex)
    {
        Cell cell;
        Row row = GetRow(sheet, rowIndex);
        if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == column + rowIndex).Any())
        {
            cell = row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == column + rowIndex).First();
        }
        else
        {
            Cell refCell = null;
            var comparer = new CellComparer();
            foreach (Cell existingCell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(existingCell.CellReference.Value, column + rowIndex) > 0)
                {
                    refCell = existingCell;
                    break;
                }
            }

            cell = new Cell { CellReference = column + rowIndex };
            row.InsertBefore(cell, refCell);
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, however it's all buried deep into styles. Consider using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) it have object model similar to old good Excel Object Model and uses OpenXML under the hood. Everything is much simplier with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExtremeML](http://extrememl.codeplex.com/releases/view/60658), it's based on OpenXML.
If use it, you can define a template, and generate excel file by template.

book1.xlsx is template, book2.xlsx is finally file. tabb1 is a table in excel 2007.

```
            FileStream fs = new FileStream ( @"d:\book1.xlsx" , FileMode.Open );
        FileStream msm = new FileStream ( @"d:\book2.xlsx" , FileMode.CreateNew );

        using ( var package = SpreadsheetDocumentWrapper.Open ( fs , msm ) ) {
            var table = package.WorkbookPart.GetTablePart ( "tabb1" ).Table;
            var data = new List<object[]> ( );

            for ( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
                data.Add ( new object[] { "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" } );
            }

            table.Fill ( data.ToArray ( ) );
        }

        fs.Close ( );
        msm.Close ( );
```